# jQuery wont show hidden children divs

Tags: jquery

Lets see this simple fiddle:

[JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejSsn/8/)

```
 <div id="a" style="display: none;">1
 <div style="display: none;">2
  <div style="display: none;">3
   <div style="display: none;">4</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
$(document).ready(function()
              {
$('#a').show('fast');
              });
```

I want to see all 1 2 3 4 but instead I only see 1. How to tell to jQuery to show all nested items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#a, #a div').show('fast');
});
```

Comment: and in case of $(this) how to select them too?

Comment: For that you can do something like: $('#a div').each(function(){$(this).//do processing// $(this) will give all the nested hidden divs})

Answer (score 1):

You need to select all elements, not just the parent...

```
$('#a, #a div').show('fast');
```

Comment: and in case of $(this) how to select them too?

Comment: @JohnSmitth I don't really understand what you mean - sorry

Answer (score 1):

In order to show all 4, just remove `display: none;` from the nested `div`s

```
<div id="a" style="display: none;">1
 <div>2
  <div>3
   <div>4</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
$(document).ready(function()
              {
$('#a').show('fast');
              });
```

Comment: and in case of $(this) how to select them too?